# Debug Spring boot app in Eclipse (STS)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to debug my spring boot app directly in STS, right click project and debug as spring boot app.  I can see the breakpoints in my controller class are getting hit fine, but it doesn't hit the breakpoints in my service class, the thread just runs through, any ideas?

Comment: Is the code inside service getting executed??

Comment: Yes it is definitely getting executed, as I am getting a valid json response back.

Comment: Just clear all break points, clean project and then set break points, it should stop in service too

Comment: Thanks that did the trick :)

Comment: for the benifit of people who face same issue i am pasting it as answer, you can accept it and do +1 so that other person wont face same issue and it will be helpful for them too

Answer (score 0):

Just clear all break points, clean project and then set break points, it should stop in service too , Hope this solves the issue